# Doctrine can't rename proxy files

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine

I'm working on an API on Symfony 4. When I call a route I get this error :

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Warning: rename(/home/api/var/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppEntityClientDonneurOrdre.php.5cd152498b5116.72752587,/home/api/var/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppEntityClientDonneurOrdre.php): No such file or directory"
```

The two files are in the folder. I don't know what to do?.

It should show my object formatted in JSON but nothing is shown except this error. There is this thing too: When I call a smaller object, that does not have any joints, it shows properly.

Could that be a problem with JMS Serializer?

Comment: have you set your cache directory to writeable?

Comment: This looks to be a permission problem on the server. Can you check if your web user can write inside the cache directory?

Comment: Using docker windows, I thought the machines had full privilege. Yet when I try to chown var as www-data:www-data, it does not seem to change.